# How to prevent browser.driver.sleep

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have the below spec which is working fine, but I want to prevent using `browser.sleep()`:

```
it('should go to the item details page', function () {
    browser.get(testOptions.baseUrl+testOptions.cpdmPath+testOptions.itemDetailsForAttachment);
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function() {
            //browser.driver.sleep('4000');
            console.log('inside then 4');                
            browser.driver.sleep('4000');
            element(by.css('.md-header-items-container')).isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible) {
                if (isVisible) {
                    // element is visible
                    browser.driver.sleep('4000');
                    element.all(by.repeater('(key, value) in tabList')).count().then(function (numberOfTabs) {
                        //console.log(numberOfTabs);
                    });
                    element.all(by.repeater('(key, value) in tabList')).get(4).click().then(function () {
                        browser.driver.sleep('4000');
                        element(by.css('.hidden-attachment-info-bar')).isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible) {
                            expect(isVisible).to.equal(true);
                        })

                    });
                } else {
                    // element is not visible
                    console.log('is invisible');
                }
            });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A common alternative to using `sleep()` with hardcoded time intervals is to use [`wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) and *explicitly wait for a specific condition to be met*. For example, wait for element to be visible:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.css('.md-header-items-container'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm), 4000);
```

Comment: Thanks @Alecxe

With your suggestion, it was giving an error at 
    var elm = element(by.css('.md-header-items-container'));
As it was trying to access the element at this very point of time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working as below:

```
it('should go to the attachments page and pass waiting time for element', function() {

    browser.get(testOptions.baseUrl+testOptions.cpdmPath+testOptions.itemDetailsForAttachment);
    browser.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(cpdmAttachTabPage.notificationBar);
    }, 90000);

   browser.driver.isElementPresent(cpdmAttachTabPage.notificationBar).then(function(isVisible) {
            console.log(isVisible);
            expect(isVisible).to.equal(true);
        })
    })
```